# Modern Screen Space Ambient Occlusion Techniques

Tags: gpu, global-illumination

Down the road, I'm planning to implement one or another GPU based ambient occlusion technique. My goal will be to approximate a physically based offline renderer, so I was pretty happy when Wikipedia led me to [Approximating Dynamic Global Illumination in Image Space](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~ritschel/Papers/SSDO.pdf), which describes SSDO. Based on the references, it looks to be from the 2008 era. Are there more modern approaches with similar accuracy goals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bachelor thesis briefly reviews six SSAO techniques. It could be a good start.

- CryEngine 2 AO
- StarCraft II AO
- HBAO
- Volumetric Obscurance
- Alchemy AO
- Unreal Engine 4 AO

http://frederikaalund.com/a-comparative-study-of-screen-space-ambient-occlusion-methods/